# tweepyであるはずのメソッドがAttributeErrorになる

Tags: python3, twitter

## やりたいこと

tweepyを利用して自動フォロバを作りたいです

## 発生している問題

リファレンスには`api.me()`が載っているのですが

```py
import tweepy
import os
import time
import asyncio
import traceback 
import keep_alive

CK = os.getenv('CK')
CS = os.getenv('CS')
AT = os.getenv('AT')
ATS = os.getenv('ATS')
auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(CK, CS)
auth.set_access_token(AT, ATS)

api = tweepy.API(auth,wait_on_rate_limit = True)
api.me()

def out_retweet():
    
    keyword = '#フォートナイト #Fortnite'
    tweet_count = 1
    for tweet in tweepy.Cursor(api.search_tweets,keyword).items(tweet_count):
        try:
            api.retweet(tweet.id) 
            print('==============')
            print('retweetしました')   
            print('---------')
            print(tweet.id)
            print(tweet.created_at)
            print(tweet.user.name)
            print(tweet.text)
            print('---------')
            print('==============')
        except Exception as e:
            print('==============')
            print('retweet済みです')
            print(tweet.text)
            print('=== エラー内容 ===')
            print(str(type(e)))
            print(str(e.args))
            print(str(e))
            print('==============')



keep_alive.keep_alive()
while True:
    out_retweet()

    time.sleep(180)
```

このコードを実行すると

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 16, in <module>
    api.me()
AttributeError: 'API' object has no attribute 'me'
```

このようなエラーが出てしまい動きません
どうすれば治りますか？

Comment: [Where did API.me go?](https://github.com/tweepy/tweepy/blob/master/docs/faq.rst#where-did-apime-go)

Comment: 版数の違いでしょうね。tweepyのv3.5.0には記述 [API.me()](https://docs.tweepy.org/en/v3.5.0/api.html#API.me) が有りますが、最新版のv4.1.0には記述がありません。[tweepy.API — Twitter API v1.1 Reference](https://docs.tweepy.org/en/v4.1.0/api.html) ChangeLogの[Version 4.0.0](https://docs.tweepy.org/en/v4.1.0/changelog.html#version-4-0-0)で`Remove API.me`ということなので、その直前版のv3.10.0に変えるか、v4.1.0を使って@metropolis さんのコメントで紹介された方法などを含めて全面的に見直しを図るかした方が良いでしょう。

Comment: なくなっちゃったんですね....
書き直してみます。。。